# Is it possible to create a map of the UK counties with the packages spData/tmap

Tags: r, tmap

I have recently used the package spData for plotting the London boroughs but I haven't found anything for plotting the counties in the UK.

Is it possible the the package spData contains only a few countries in it?

Thank you for your help,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Could [this](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/11302ddc-65bc-4a8f-96a9-af5c456e442c/counties-and-unitary-authorities-december-2016-full-clipped-boundaries-in-england-and-wales) be what you are looking for? A shp of the counties?

Answer (score 0):

spData isn't a complete set of world spatial data.

You can find a complete set (with good county shapes) in the [Natural Earth 10m (high resolution) cultural vectors](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/). Here's how I was able to make a quick map of UK counties, coloured by the length of the county name:

```
library("tmap")
library("tmaptools")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthhires")
library("sf")
data("states10")
uk_counties <- states10[which(states10$iso_a2 =="GB"),]
uk_counties = st_as_sf(uk_counties)
qtm(uk_counties, fill="name_len")
```

Once you have this dataframe called uk_counties, you can join it to your data & quickly make some nice maps.

[choropleth of uk counties by length of county name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsovb.png)